# jquery how to count all xml nodes of one type with a certain type of parent node

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

From my XML I'd like to get the number of `chaper` nodes that are nested in `video` nodes. Getting the total number of `chaper` nodes works with

```
$(xml).find("chapter").length
```

What is the syntax to add the `video` parent node requirement?

Comment: `.find` accepts any selector, so you can just do `.find('video > chapter')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for :

```
$(xml).find("video > chapter").length
```